# Vertical-Align: A Full Explanation

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've been struggling with vertical alignments, a seemingly simple enough process that has a lot of idiosyncrasies throughout different languages and element types. I've done a lot of reading through stackexchange and can't seem to find a common thread of understanding.

Here are the rules that I have been able to gather:

1) Vertical-align does not work in `<\div>`s, you have to set `div {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle}`

This seems like a big hassle, especially since table-cells override the height limitation even when overflow is set to hidden and expands to fit content, which means the vertical "center" is variable.

I just read some source-code from Pinterest where `button {vertical-align: middle}`, but no other `vertical-align` commands seem to work. It seems as if button is by default aligned in the middle.

Can someone provide a clear explanation for the `vertical-align` attribute?

What html elements *respond to* `vertical-align`?

Which html elements have *default* `vertical-align` attributes?

Which html elements have *non-overridable* `vertical-align` attributes?

And any clues as to understanding the idiosyncracies would help as  well!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not assume that button is not amenable to vertical-align. Both the button itself, and its contents are vertical aligned to the baseline just like any other inline-level element. See http://jsfiddle.net/UrgmU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vertical-align are two options

**One** On the element.

Vertical-align works for `inline` elements not block elements. Then you can set the proeperty directly in the element to be aligned with other inline elements.

**Two** On the container

You can set the property on the container like a `table-cell`. You can vertical-align the elements on a `td` or fake it with two `divs` one with `display:table` and inside a `display:table-cell` div who has vertical-align his content.

Comment: Good answer. A couple of nit-picks. (i) Vertical-align works for `inline-level` elements, not just `inline` ones. i.e. it works for `inline-block` and `inline-table` elements too. (ii) Generally, you don't need the `display:table` div as the browser will create an anonymous table wrapper anyway. The exception is when the `display:table-cell` element has a percentage height.

Answer (score 0):

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Just go through the link it will help you a bit not as much as you want but just a rough idea :)